# AndroidRuntime error at com.example.appname.MainActivity.onCreate

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, mobile-application

I am trying to write Java code that creates a button click event that populates an edit text box with my name. Unfortunately I am getting runtime errors. I checked almost all related topics and questions on stackoverflow but couldn't figure it out my problem.
Appreciated for your helps.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.question5;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button b;
    EditText et;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                et.setText("My Name");          
            }
        });     
    }
}
```

fragment_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.question5.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="178dp"
        android:text="Populate" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="54dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.question5"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.question5.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Error LogCat

```
03-21 23:38:26.227: W/dalvikvm(28343): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40bfd1f8)
03-21 23:38:26.227: E/AndroidRuntime(28343): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-21 23:38:26.227: E/AndroidRuntime(28343): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.question5/com.example.question5.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-21 23:38:26.227: E/AndroidRuntime(28343):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1970)
03-21 23:38:26.227: E/AndroidRuntime(28343):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1995)
03-21 23:38:26.227: E/AndroidRuntime(28343):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:128)
03-21 23:38:26.227: E/AndroidRuntime(28343):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1161)
03-21 23:38:26.227: E/AndroidRuntime(28343):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-21 23:38:26.227: E/AndroidRuntime(28343):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-21 23:38:26.227: E/AndroidRuntime(28343):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
03-21 23:38:26.227: E/AndroidRuntime(28343):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-21 23:38:26.227: E/AndroidRuntime(28343):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-21 23:38:26.227: E/AndroidRuntime(28343):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
03-21 23:38:26.227: E/AndroidRuntime(28343):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
03-21 23:38:26.227: E/AndroidRuntime(28343):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-21 23:38:26.227: E/AndroidRuntime(28343): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-21 23:38:26.227: E/AndroidRuntime(28343):    at com.example.question5.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
03-21 23:38:26.227: E/AndroidRuntime(28343):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
03-21 23:38:26.227: E/AndroidRuntime(28343):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1053)
03-21 23:38:26.227: E/AndroidRuntime(28343):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1934)
03-21 23:38:26.227: E/AndroidRuntime(28343):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `fragment_main.xml` instead of `activity_main.xml` for MainActivity layout because Button and EditText is in `fragment_main` with id's by which you are trying to access in MainActivity :

```
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
```

Comment: is it really:):) i spend my 7-8 hours to find error and haven't checked xml file name:) Thank you very much. now it is working.